# Check a value in my database and add class to html

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller

I am looking for a way to watch for my date + month in my database, and IF that date to a spesefic month allready is taken, it should add `class="hidden"` To my dropdown, where a user book a time.

I have made the following that i can't make work, am i compleatly lost, or am i on the right way?

**Controller:**

```
var day = Request.Form["day"];
var month = Request.Form["mouth"];
var CheckDate = db.BookTimes.Where(m => m.Month.Equals(month) & m.Date.Equals(day)).Any();
```

**Model:**

```
public class BookTime
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public int Zip { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Month { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
}
```

**Html:**

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
        <b>Månede</b>
        <select class="form-control" name="Month" required>
            <option>Vælg Månede</option>
            <option value="Januar">Januar</option>
            <option value="Febuar">Febuar</option>
            <option value="Marts">Marts</option>
            <!-- Annd it keeps going like this to december-->
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <b>Dag</b>
        <select class="form-control" name="Date" required>
            <option>Vælg Dato</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <!--It keeps going like that to 31-->
        </select>
    </div>
<br /><br /><br />
    <hr />
    <button id="SendBtn" class="btn btn-success">Send</button>
```

**Jquery:**

```
if (! CheckDate){
    $(this).addClass("hidden")
}
```

What can i do to make it so that if that date allready is selected it should add class hidden to the option?

Comment: Sounds like you have a backend process. You could conflict the selected data (when both are valid) on lost focus (for example) with the DB data through an AJAX request and return some boolean, if false you apply the rule you want. This grants you to use 100% from JS in your app.

Comment: @RodrigoQuiñonesPichioli I was thinking, and yeah it seems like i need to do it in backend :i